# Identifying Lie Subgroup Corresponding to Lie Subalgebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Starting with the double cover of the conformal group of Minkowski space, $SO_0(2,4)$, let $\mathfrak{M}^{AB}$ be the generators (basis elements) of the corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2,4)$ where $A,B = 0,...,5$. I have identified a Lie subalgebra generated by the elements

$$
P_-: = P_1 - P_2 = \mathfrak{M}^{10}+ \mathfrak{M}^{15} - \mathfrak{M}^{20}- \mathfrak{M}^{25}
$$

$$
K_+: = K_1 + K_2 = \mathfrak{M}^{10}- \mathfrak{M}^{15} + \mathfrak{M}^{20}- \mathfrak{M}^{25}
$$

$$
M^3 : = iH + M^{12} = \mathfrak{M}^{05} - \mathfrak{M}^{12}
$$

with commutation relations $[P_-, K_+] = - 4 i M^3$, $[P_-, M^3] = - 2 i P_-$, $[K_+, M^3] = 2 i K_+$. This algebra is isomorphic over the reals to $\mathfrak{so}(2,1, \Bbb{R}) \simeq \mathfrak{sl}(2, \Bbb{R}) \simeq \mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ via the mapping $\tilde{M}^{01} = - \frac{1}{2} (P_- + K_+), \tilde{M}^{02} = - \frac{1}{2}(P_- - K_+), \tilde{M}^{12}= \frac{1}{2}M^3$ where $\tilde{M}^{ij}$ are the generators of $\mathfrak{so}(2,1, \Bbb{R})$.

I want to be able to say something about the global topology of the Lie subgroup generated by $\{P_-, K_+, M^3\}$ and therefore I would like to identify the Lie subgroup it generates. **My question is thus: how can I identify the Lie subgroup generated by $\{P_-, K_+, M^3\}$?**

It appears the answer could be either $SO(2,1)$ or $SL(2, \Bbb{R}) \simeq SU(1,1)$, which have different topologies (the former being non-compact and not connected while the latter is non-compact and connected) but I do not know of how to distinguish between these given the information I have. My hope was there is some constraint coming from the topology of the ambient group $SO_0(2,4)$ which is connected and non-compact [1]. Along this line of thinking I know of the standard Lie subgroup-subalgebra theorems found in [2] describing the existence of a unique connected Lie subgroup to every Lie subalgebra. However, I don't believe this helps me (it actually confuses me because $SO_0(2,1)$ and $SL(2, \Bbb{R})$ are both connected but not isomorphic).

Finally, if there is no way to identify the Lie subgroup from the given information, and it is the case that I need some more global information about the Lie subgroup, what information could that be? Is there a calculation I could do or theorem I could use? Perhaps there is a way to move around on the submanifold which represents the Lie subgroup corresponding to $\{P_-, K_+, M^3\}$ and calculate the curvature or some global characteristic to distinguish between the Lie subgroups?

---

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) 
[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group%E2%80%93Lie_algebra_correspondence)

Comment: Well, $SO_0(2,1) \simeq PSL_2(\mathbb R)$ which is the quotient of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ w.r.t. its centre $\pm Id$ -- see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76827/96384. Maybe that at least alleviates the confusion at the end of the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: Actually, there is an infinite tower of real Lie groups which share the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)#Topology_and_universal_cover; it seems though that only the two you mentioned, $SL_2$ and $PSL_2$, are matrix Lie groups, thus indeed we must decide between those two. Well, their "global" distinction is that one has a centre consisting of two elements, and the other's centre is trivial. That should be decidable once you clarify what it means for the subgroup to be "generated" by elements of the Lie algebra -- I assume, their exponentials?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, by ''generate'' I mean taking the exponentials of the Lie algebra elements. Also, you're suggesting we must choose between $SL_2$ and $PSL_2$ simply because they are finite dimensional matrix Lie groups and the ambient space is also finite dimensional?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg And is it the case that simply computing the center of the Lie algebra will indicate whether or not it is $SL_2$ or $PSL_2$ based on it being trivial or non-trivial?

Comment: We must chose between those two because (to my knowledge) indeed they are the only ones who have the Lie algebra in question and have faithful finite dimensional i.e. matrix representations (and our subgroup has that by being a subgroup of $SO(2,4)$). As for the second question, computing the centre of the *group* (the subgroup of $SO(2,4)$ you're interested in) will decide whether it is isomorphic to $SL_2$ or $PSL_2$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Okay, great. Although there is a relationship between a trivial Lie algebra center and a zero-dimensional Lie group center (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883131/center-of-lie-group-and-lie-algebra), the Lie group center is not necessarily trivial in that case i.e. proportional to the identity which is why we can't compute this at the Lie algebra level in this problem, correct?

Comment: Correct. By the way, do you know what the centre of your ambient group $SO(2,4)$ is?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Well, following https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103900926, pg. 6, it looks like the conformal group of Minkowski space, defined to be $SO(2,4)/ \Bbb{Z}_2$, has trivial center.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Is this fact about the center of $SO_0(2,4)$ supposed to help in anyway? If so, I can't see it. I'm also having trouble figuring out how to compute the center of an arbitrary Lie group. Any recommends/references on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, computing the centre of an arbitrary Lie group is not necessarily easy. But yes, I thought this all might help: One should check if $SO_0(2,4)$ contains $-Id$, and if so, if there is an element in the Lie algebra which exponentiates to it. Using that e.g. $\pmatrix{0&-\pi\\ \pi&0} \in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ exponentiates to $-Id \in SL_2$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg In which case if $-Id$ was produced by the elements in my subalgebra, then we could conclude it contained $\Bbb{Z}_2$ which would allow us to identify it as $SL_2$. I don't know this but I have another idea: Let us assume the ambient group is $G = SO_0(2,4)$ then I believe, given a second [source](http://www.theorie.physik.uni-goettingen.de/forschung/qft/research/theses/dipl/Meise.pdf) on pg. 17, it has a $\Bbb{Z}_2$ center. Then, since $Z(G) \subseteq Z(H)$ for any subgroup $H$, we would know the center of the elements generated by this subalgebra...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg  ...have at least a $\Bbb{Z}_2$ center which would identify the subgroup as being $ H = SL_2$, given the choices. Furthermore, if modding out $G$ and $H$ by $\Bbb{Z}_2$ produces $SO_0(2,4)/\Bbb{Z}_2$ and $PSL_2$, given the Lie subalgebra generating this $PSL_2$ doesn't change, we can conclude if $SO_0(2,4)/\Bbb{Z}_2$ is the ambient group, then the subalgebra generated by these elements must be $PSL_2$? Does this sound plausible?

Comment: That is plausible in principle, but one has to be careful. Most importantly, it is not true that $Z(G) \subseteq Z(H)$ for every subgroup $H$, rather $H \cap Z(G) \subseteq Z(H)$, and that throws us back to checking whether $-Id$ can be "produced" by elements in your subalgebra. I recommend checking that by hand, by using my abovementioned element of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and checking what element it corresponds to in your presentation via following through the isomorphisms. (I am pretty convinced now that the subgroup everyone writes as $\mathbb Z_2$ here is $\lbrace \pm Id \rbrace$).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Okay. First I agree with your comment on the actual elements of the group which compose the $$\Bbb{Z}_2  factor here. I've performed this calculation (I can explain if you're interested as it's pretty straight forward once you pick the right defining rep for the $\mathfrak{M}^{{AB}}$) and I am finding the corresponding group element produced with my generators does not produce $-Id$ in $SO_0(2,4)$. I also know what elements exponentiate to $-Id$ and the needed element is not in the Lie subalgebra I have listed...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Given this, does it sound like we can conclude the Lie subgroup must be $PSL_2(\Bbb{R})$?

Comment: If you could amend those computations, that would be great.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Certainly. Using the basis for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_Lie_algebra), I find the mapping $e = - \frac{P_-}{2} , f = - \frac{K_+}{2}, h = -i M^3 $ is an isomorphism. The element $\pi \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) = \pi (f-e) \in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ then corresponds to $-\frac{\pi}{2}(K_+ - P_-) = \pi ( \mathfrak{M}^{15} - \mathfrak{M}^{20} )$. A defining rep of $\mathfrak{so}(2,4)$ on $\Bbb{R}^{2,4}$ can be given by...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $[\mathfrak{M}^{AB}]^i_{\ j} = - (g^{Ai} \delta^B_{\ j} - g^{Bi} \delta^A_{\ j})$ (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28535/lie-bracket-for-lie-algebra-of-son-m) for example) where g = diag$(-1,-1,1,1,1,1)$. Then I just exponentiated $\pi ( \mathfrak{M}^{15} - \mathfrak{M}^{20})$ and did not get $-Id$. Then, it is not too hard to see that the element $\exp[\pi (\mathfrak{M}^{01} + \mathfrak{M}^{25} + \mathfrak{M}^{34})]$ gives $-Id$, although this combination of generators is not unique. Finally, $\mathfrak{M}^{34}$ is not in my subalgebra.